# VSCode auto import React built-in hooks like useState, useEffect

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, react-hooks, auto-import

In VSCode, how can I get auto import suggestions for React built-in hooks, like `useState`, `useEffect`, etc?

Just like what we get in CodeSandbox:

[image]

Enabled extensions (maybe there is some conflict between them, though I'm not getting any errors):

[image]

Comment: I've been using this extension for that. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=steoates.autoimport

Comment: when i define one of each hooks, other hooks can add but when was not hook imported not work.

Comment: Not sure what I did to fix it. But maybe I didn't have `"@types/react" and "@types/react-dom"` installed back then. You should install those.

Comment: I use a mix of JS and TS and I found https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NuclleaR.vscode-extension-auto-import. I can confirm it works with JSX useState.

Answer (score 1):

So, one thing you can do is try updating your local settings file:

inside your project directory:

`<project>/.vscode/settings.json`

```
{
  // other vscode settings specific to this project...
  "typescript.suggest.autoImports": true, // or
  "javascript.suggest.autoImports": true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, extensions interfere with the functionality. With me, Vetur(Vue extension) was interfering with the React auto imports. I had to disable, and restart the VS Code. Now I can auto import from React. I enabled the Vetur again and restarted VS Code. Both Vue and React is working fine.

In the end, check if you are able to see the issue with some extension.